# tkinter LabelFrame not attatching widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

I am running into a problem with a tkinter program, I have the LabelFrame grouping a set of labels and entries, however, it is not grouping my widgets. My code for the LabelFrame is as follows:

(edit: i managed to get the Label to display, however, it is not grouping my widgets.)

```
root=Tk()
message_frame=LabelFrame(root,text="testing",padx=0,pady=0,width=100,height=100).grid(padx=5,pady=10)

message_label=Label(message_frame,text="Message").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
pub_label=Label(message_frame,text="Public Key").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
priv_label=Label(message_frame,text="Public Key").grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)

message_entry=Entry(message_frame,textvariable=message,width=50).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
pub_entry=Entry(message_frame,textvariable=pub_key,width=50).grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
priv_entry=Entry(message_frame,textvariable=private_key,width=50).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tkinter, the typical workflow is to create a widget and then place it using some geometry manager ***on two separate lines***.

If I'm not mistaken, the `.grid` method on Tkinter widgets returns `None`.  So if you `print message_frame` right after you create it, you will probably see that it is `None`.  When you use that passed to the next widgets, they assume you want to put it on the root widget...

The easy fix is to do something like:

```
message_frame=LabelFrame(root,text="testing",padx=0,pady=0,width=100,height=100)
message_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

And you probably want to do the same with all the widgets since I doubt you actually want `pub_label` = `priv_label` = `None` ...

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I've never understood why people combine pack or grid with widget creation, there must be a tutorial out there that advocates that...

Comment: @BryanOakley You could do it if subclassed it and made `pack` and `grid` return `self` ... But I think it's just a natural thing to want to do.  I doubt that any tutorial would advocate that since it would be terribly difficult to retrieve your handle on the widget to do anything with it ...

Comment: I think that what Bryan said is that there are so many people using this error-prone pattern that there must exist a place where someone advocates (or provides examples) of this use. This seems natural to me with a Smalltalk background, but I don't think it is such spread. In Python (as well as other widespread language), you do not expect "procedure" to return self.

Comment: @FabienAndre I understand what Bryan was saying...It just seems like such a bad thing to do that I have a hard time imagining anyone knowledgable enough to write a tutorial would make that "mistake"...I guess it would be OK to do if you were just creating labels that you don't plan on doing anything with later...  That said, since it is so common, I wonder if there would be any harm in making `grid`, `pack`, `place` return `self`?

Comment: @BryanOakley  After few searches, it may come from a straight translation of perl/tk code, in which pack and grid call on the same line reveals quite common...

Comment: @FabienAndre From perl?  It makes me a little sad that anything from perl would come over into python ... Thanks for digging that up though.  I was quite curious.

Answer (score 2):

Give the frame some size attributes:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()  
message_frame = LabelFrame(root,text="testing",padx=0,pady=0,width=100,height=100).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
```

Once the width and height are defined, the frame shows up fine.
If you post some of your frame's contents, it might make it clearer if this is not the issue.