# Tkinter: nested LabelFrame (s) not shown

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to split  a `LabelFrame` into two [label frames](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm). So first, I created an other `LabelFrame` and tested if it displays well. But no, it is not displayed.

But when I change `childLabelFrame` to a simple `Label` or a simple `Frame` I see it displayed well.

I read some similar questions such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326330/tkinter-labelframe-not-attatching-widgets), but I did not do those errors in my case.

```
mainLabelFrame=LabelFrame(parent,text="Description:",padx=20,pady=20,200, width=400,relief=RIDGE)          
childLabelFrame=LabelFrame(mainLabelFrame,text="Help",relief=RIDGE)
childLabelFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)    
mainLabelFrame.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=E+W)
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems to show once you put something else into the child label frame.

Comment: As @tobias_k pointed out , adding some internal padding would also help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `childLabelFrame` has zero size and thus is not drawn. Indeed, both `childLabelFrame.winfo_width()` and `childLabelFrame.winfo_height()` return `1`.

It is drawn correctly if

- you specify a size, like `childLabelFrame = LabelFrame(mainLabelFrame, text="Help", height=100, width=200)`, or
- you add something inside the child label frame, e.g. `Label(childLabelFrame, text="label").grid()`.

Comment: I thought because of the text it has, I did not need to set the size since it would stretch itself automatically to display that text. So the idea of setting its size never came to my mind. Thank you very much, it works as you said.

Comment: @Nakkini That is indeed strange, as the minimum size for the `mainLabelFrame` seems to be based on the text. I don't know what's the reason, but at least it seems to work that way. No, wait... if you remove the child, the parent also has size 0... but even with the size-0-child it has correct minimum size... strange, indeed.

Comment: I got the same problem . Changing the `mainLabelFrame.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=E+W)` to `mainLabelFrame.pack(fill="both" , expand = True )` did it for me.